# Enter value in cell, have display value result of formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm sure there's a very easy answer to this (and I don't know that I have the excel chops to ask the "right" question, or google would give me the answer).

I have the following formula:

```
=DATE(YEAR(V1), MONTH(V1)+V2-1,8)
```

I'd like to be able to enter a number into a cell (say, 14) and have that formula run, except the number that I enter into the cell should replace the number 8 in the formula. So, again, entering 14, the formula that would execute would be:

```
=DATE(YEAR(V1), MONTH(V1)+V2-1, 14)
```

So to recap, the workflow is this:

1. I enter the value '14' into cell A3.
2. The above formula is executed
3. The displayed value of A3 is something like 3/14/2012    (depending on my V1/V2 cell values)

Can I do this without VBA? (I'm a .NET programmer by trade, so VBA isn't foreign to me, I just feel like Excel should be able to do this native without code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - because you are transferring a value in A3 via a formula into a new value within A3.

The code below will update A1:A5 when any of these cells are changed (all 5 if all are changed at once) with the result you ask for

1. right click your sheet tab
2. View Code
3. Copy and paste the code below

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim rng1 As Range
   Dim rng2 As Range
   Set rng1 = Intersect(Range("a1:A5"), Target)
   If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   For Each rng2 In rng1
       rng2.Value = Format(Evaluate("DATE(YEAR(V1), MONTH(V1)+V2-1," & CLng(rng2.Value) & ")"), "mm/dd/yyyy")
   Next rng2
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Works to perfection. Thanks Brett.